# TypeError: %x format: an integer is required, not bytes

Tags: python-3.x, casting, format, typeerror, pyserial

I am trying to interface between a radio and computer via USB. Here is the code that I am using:

```
def __getSync(self, raise_error=True):
    c = self.__recv(raise_error)
    if c is None:
        return False
    if (c != self.INSYNC):
        self.debug("unexpected 0x%x instead of INSYNC (0x%x)" % (c, self.INSYNC))
        if raise_error:
            raise RuntimeError("unexpected 0x%x instead of INSYNC (0x%x)" % (c, self.INSYNC))
        return False
    c = self.__recv()
    if (c != self.OK):
        self.debug("unexpected 0x%x instead of OK (0x%x)" % (c, self.OK))
        if raise_error:
            raise RuntimeError("unexpected 0x%x instead of OK (0x%x)" % (c, self.OK))
        return False
    self.debug("__getSync OK", 2)
    return True
```

And when I do I receive the the following message:

```
Traceback(most recent call last):    
    File "uploader.py", line 152, in __getSync
        self.debug("unexpected 0x%x instead of INSYNC (0x%x)" % (c, self.INSYNC))
TypeError: %x format: an integer is required, not bytes
```

I have tried int.from_bytes(c, "big") only to have 'bytes' in the error message be replaced with 'str'. Anybody able to give any help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

`xxx.hex()` works for me, it parses bytes to hex string